# Highcharts não lê JSON do Banco Central

Tags: json, highcharts

Estou usando o https://cloud.highcharts.com  e quero criar um gráfico dinamico (live data) usando esse Json do BCB:  http://api.bcb.gov.br/dados/serie/bcdata.sgs.24887/dados?formato=json

O problema é que o `Highcharts` não importa de maneira alguma desta URL, não dá erro, não acusa nada.

Alguém sabe como resolver? Será que ele não lê esse tipo de `JSON` do `BCB`? Também testei com CSV e não funcionou.

[image: highcharts]

hoje está assim o JSON:

```
[{"data":"01/01/2013","valor":"17.87"},{"data":"01/02/2013","valor":"17.74"},{"data":"01/03/2013","valor":"17.62"},{"data":"01/04/2013","valor":"17.54"},{"data":"01/05/2013","valor":"17.45"},{"data":"01/06/2013","valor":"17.40"},{"data":"01/07/2013","valor":"17.36"},{"data":"01/08/2013","valor":"17.38"},{"data":"01/09/2013","valor":"17.43"},{"data":"01/10/2013","valor":"17.48"},{"data":"01/11/2013","valor":"17.52"},{"data":"01/12/2013","valor":"17.57"},{"data":"01/01/2014","valor":"17.67"},{"data":"01/02/2014","valor":"17.79"},{"data":"01/03/2014","valor":"17.88"},{"data":"01/04/2014","valor":"18.00"},{"data":"01/05/2014","valor":"18.08"},{"data":"01/06/2014","valor":"18.14"},{"data":"01/07/2014","valor":"18.25"},{"data":"01/08/2014","valor":"18.32"},{"data":"01/09/2014","valor":"18.41"},{"data":"01/10/2014","valor":"18.48"},{"data":"01/11/2014","valor":"18.57"},{"data":"01/12/2014","valor":"18.63"},{"data":"01/01/2015","valor":"18.73"},{"data":"01/02/2015","valor":"18.84"},{"data":"01/03/2015","valor":"18.97"},{"data":"01/04/2015","valor":"19.09"},{"data":"01/05/2015","valor":"19.24"},{"data":"01/06/2015","valor":"19.33"},{"data":"01/07/2015","valor":"19.44"},{"data":"01/08/2015","valor":"19.52"},{"data":"01/09/2015","valor":"19.64"},{"data":"01/10/2015","valor":"19.77"},{"data":"01/11/2015","valor":"19.91"},{"data":"01/12/2015","valor":"20.06"},{"data":"01/01/2016","valor":"20.20"},{"data":"01/02/2016","valor":"20.35"},{"data":"01/03/2016","valor":"20.51"},{"data":"01/04/2016","valor":"20.65"},{"data":"01/05/2016","valor":"20.77"},{"data":"01/06/2016","valor":"20.90"},{"data":"01/07/2016","valor":"20.98"},{"data":"01/08/2016","valor":"21.05"},{"data":"01/09/2016","valor":"21.11"},{"data":"01/10/2016","valor":"21.17"},{"data":"01/11/2016","valor":"21.25"},{"data":"01/12/2016","valor":"21.25"},{"data":"01/01/2017","valor":"21.31"},{"data":"01/02/2017","valor":"21.33"},{"data":"01/03/2017","valor":"21.29"},{"data":"01/04/2017","valor":"21.22"},{"data":"01/05/2017","valor":"21.06"},{"data":"01/06/2017","valor":"20.92"},{"data":"01/07/2017","valor":"20.74"},{"data":"01/08/2017","valor":"20.49"},{"data":"01/09/2017","valor":"20.27"},{"data":"01/10/2017","valor":"19.97"},{"data":"01/11/2017","valor":"19.69"},{"data":"01/12/2017","valor":"19.39"},{"data":"01/01/2018","valor":"19.16"},{"data":"01/02/2018","valor":"18.87"},{"data":"01/03/2018","valor":"18.47"},{"data":"01/04/2018","valor":"18.08"},{"data":"01/05/2018","valor":"17.77"}]
```

Comment: Você consegue salvar como está hoje e postar aqui o link para vermos?

Comment: Independente se você incluir um JSON externo, você deve tratar as SERIES, ou seja, as Labels do gráfico.

Comment: editei acima para facilitar